# ClickOnce winform does not open from start menu, after windows udates, starts working again after one/multiple computer restarts

Tags: vb.net, outlook, office365, office-interop, clickonce

Since some time the vb.net application I developed stops working for some users, usually after windows 10 updates. It starts working again after restarting computer one or more times, sometimes it takes few days for it to start.

When user tries to reinstall it, it is installed but throws following error:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {X} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

I'm assuming that it has something to do with a Outlook Interop reference in the project.

When outlook is closed and I run this application as admin I am able to start it, when outlook is open I am not able to do it.

When both outlook and the application are open with admin privilegesit works correctly.

I understand that Outlook and the application should run with the same security level, but I'm not running outlook as admin so I'm confused why I need to run the app as admin.

The target CPU is set to 'Any CPU', should I maybe try changing it to 'X86'?

Office version is Office365 Pro

Comment: Do you try to automate from a Windows service? Where and when do you try to automate Outlook?

Comment: And why do you need to automate Outlook? Have you considered using any other possible routes like EWS or Graph API?

Comment: I'm trying to create email drafts and save them in current user outlook inbox

Comment: Where and when are you trying to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run both applications under the same security context. If both are run under the same user - everything should work correctly.

However, the following error may indicate that Office applications are automated from a service:

> 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

The [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article states the following for such errors:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Comment: I have just checked and users cannot install any clickonce app, even with just a message box. So I dont believe this is a matter of office automation

Comment: Have you checked the log? See [Troubleshoot ClickOnce deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/troubleshooting-clickonce-deployments?view=vs-2022)